# Telegraf (Tick stack)

Tags: telegraf-output-plugins

Any one Plz answer my question, if u have known the answer:

I have two telegraf agents one in windows system and other in linux centos server. I also have one influxdb database.

Question is: in my windows telegraf config file I have given the db name as telegraf_one and in centos telegraf config file I have given the same db name i.e., `telegraf_one`.
On my influxdb server I have db telegraf_one created when running windows telegraf, and later I have been starting the telegraf agent in centos, will db conflicts occur due to same db name from different telegraf agents or both telegraf agents use the same db without conflicts.

Comment: no. Try it and send any errors if you find, that can help narrow down any issues

Answer (score 0):

No conflict will occur. Both agents will report metrics to the same db server under respective os.host() names. This is actually how telegraf is designed to function.